# How to get the id rather than labelKey from typeahead when an array of objects is passed through?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I have my react-bootstrap-typeahead setup like this:

```
// MusicServices.jsx
import React, {Fragment, useState} from 'react';
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Typeahead } from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';

const MusicServices = ({services}) => {
  const [musicServiceID, setMusicServiceSelection] = useState([]);
  const [transferDetailID, setTransferDetailSelection] = useState([]);

  const musicServiceDetails = Object.keys(services).map((serviceID) => {
    return {
        id: serviceID,
        name: services[serviceID].name
    }
  });

  const getTransferDetails = () => {
    let transferDetailSelections = []
    if (musicServiceID.length) {
      transferDetailSelections = services[musicServiceID[0].id].transferDetails;
    }
    return (
      <Form.Group>
         <Form.Label>Transfer Details</Form.Label>
         <Typeahead
          name="transferdetail"
          id="transfer-detail"
          labelKey="name"
          onChange={setTransferDetailSelection}
          options={transferDetailSelections}
          placeholder="Choose a Transfer Detail..."
          selected={transferDetailID}
         />
       </Form.Group>
    )
  }
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Label>Music Services</Form.Label>
        <Typeahead
          name="musicservice"
          id="music-service"
          labelKey="name"
          onChange={(selected) => {
            setMusicServiceSelection(selected)
          }}
          options={musicServiceDetails}
          placeholder="Choose a music service..."
          selected={musicServiceID}
        />
      </Form.Group>
      {getTransferDetails()}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default MusicServices;
```

I use the same code ina. few places so I extracted it out to it's own function...

SO I use it in a form like this:

```
import React from 'react';
const Jumbotron = require('react-bootstrap').Jumbotron;
const Container = require('react-bootstrap').Container;
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
const Button = require('react-bootstrap').Button;

import MusicServices from '../../components/auth/MusicServices';


const Generate = ({services}) => {
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    const formEvent = event.currentTarget;
    console.log(event.target.elements)

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  };

  let mservices = {123455: {name: 'abc', transferDetails: [{id: 6789, name: 'der'}]}}

  return (
    <>
      <Jumbotron>
        <Container>
          <h1 className="display-3">Generate</h1>
          <p>{session.user.name}, this will generate a new key pair to be stored on the filestore and against a transfer detail.</p>
        </Container>
      </Jumbotron>
      <Container>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Group controlId="service">
            <MusicServices services={mservices}></MusicServices>
          </Form.Group>
          <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
            Generate key pair
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}

export default Generate
```

In my `handleSubmit()` function, I want to get the value of the `transfer-detail` typeahead, but the value is coming back as "der".  What I really want is the "6789" id value, with the "der" being displayed to the user to typeahead on.

I can't see how to get this value.  At a guess it's in `transferDetailID`, but that doesn't seem  available in my Generate.jsx page.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `getTransferDetails` function? Any reason you're not just rendering that typeahead inline?

Comment: I'm very new at attempting to write react code, so my code is probably quite poor.  However, the purpose is that the inline `music-service` field is changed, the `transfer-detail` is then updated with a list of options... a data structure that looks like: `{12345: {name: 'abc', transferDetails: [{id: 4567, name: 'aaa'}]}}` so when music-service 12345 is selected, transfer-detail is populated with the related transferDetails array.  Someone had suggested the way to do it is via state hoisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `useState` hooks need to be in the parent and passed down to the child, so in this instance, they need to be taken from the `MusicServices` functional Component and put into the `Generate` functional Component.

You then have to pass both the variable and the setter through to the child.  So in the `Generate` functional component I have changed the code:

```
const Generate = ({services}) => {
  const [musicServiceID, setMusicServiceSelection] = useState([]);
  const [transferDetailID, setTransferDetailSelection] = useState([]);
  return (
    <>
      ...
      <Container>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Group controlId="service">
            {
              MusicServices(
                services,
                musicServiceID,
                setMusicServiceSelection,
                transferDetailID,
                setTransferDetailSelection
              )
            }
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
       </Container>
       ...
    </>
  )
};
```

this then allows the `handleSubmit` function access to the states of `musicServiceID` and `transferDetailID`.